# Running parallel tasks with error handling and no fail-fast

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

We got in our code a task runner. We retrieve some ids to run the task on from a remote source, so we can't know at code writing stage how many tasks we will run in parallel.

Important to us, we need **proper error handling** for each task to shows in the final result (so if an error occurs in any task execution, we can trigger another cleanup action). Also **we don't want fail-fast behaviour**: if any tasks fails, we don't want other tasks to fail. As said before we'll handle this separately.

Here is our code:

```
function doTask(param){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      if(param ===2)
        reject('failed ' + param);
      resolve('done ' + param)
    }, 1000 - param)
  })
}

let ids = [1,2,3]; // This array of ID is retrieved from remote source
let tasks = ids.map(doTask);
const startTime = performance.now();

console.log(`Tasks starting...`);
Promise.all(tasks.map(p => p.catch(e => e)))
  .then(results => console.log(`Task finished in ${ performance.now() - startTime } miliseconds with,`, results))
  .catch(e => console.log('should not happen but we never know', e));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bjev4u5o/1/

It works, but my curiosity leads me to ask if there is any better way to write that. And especially maybe the `async / await` techniques could help us?

Comment: That `.catch(e => e)` doesn't look like the "*proper error handling*" you were talking about :-)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how this is done. `async`/`await` syntax can act as sugar instead of `then` calls, but it does not introduce a new approach to solving this.

Comment: @Bergi Indeed the error handling may not be the most efficient. What are your recommendations on that? I just want to push the error in the result array along with the faulty ID. e.g: `{id: x, res: '', err: the error}`

Comment: I just was referring to your example with the clean-up action, which should go in that `catch` handler. Otherwise, yes, you just have to return something that can be identified as an error in the processing of your array of results. It depends on what errors your promises reject with, and what the normal results look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be an async/await version (I wrote it in typescript but should be the same in JS minus the type annotation on `wrapTask`). Weather there is any improvement over the classical version is debatable in this case.

```
function doTask(param) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (param === 2) reject('failed ' + param);
            resolve('done ' + param)
        }, 1000 - param)
    })
}

async function doAll() {
    async function wrapTask(promise: Promise<any>) {
        try {
            return await promise;
        } catch (e) {
            return e;
        }
    }
    let ids = [1, 2, 3]; // This array of ID is retrieved from remote source
    let tasks = ids
        .map(doTask);

    const startTime = performance.now();

    console.log(`Tasks starting...`);
    try {
        let results = await Promise.all(tasks.map(wrapTask));
        console.log(`Task finished in ${performance.now() - startTime} miliseconds with,`, results)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('should not happen but we never know', e)
    }
}

doAll();
```